# Numpy Python Numerical Errors

Tags: python, macos, numpy, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

when using the numpy module on my computer, in particular np.linalg.solve, I am getting numerical errors in the outputs that I do not get when running the same exact code on other computers. I have tried deleting and re-downloading anaconda and updating numpy however this does not fix things, and sometimes I would even get larger numerical errors. I am using MacOSX I have no ideas what is causing this and I would greatly appreciate any help on the issue.
Thanks

Comment: It's hard to anyone to have any idea what could be causing this without any inkling what you're actually doing

Comment: I have a matrix and I am trying to compute the inverse using linalg.solve. I've tried using np.linalg.inv but I get the same thing

Comment: I mean, you need to provide runnable code that demonstrates the issue and a detailed specification of each system (platform, other libraries in the environment). right now, your question can be boiled down to "i have code on my machine that produces unexpected output"

Comment: Hi, I see. Sorry about that. I will try and frase it better next time. I have somewhat fixed my problem. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

As a test, maybe create a new environment and only install numpy and its dependencies.

Comment: just tried it, didn't change, but thank you for your help